# powershell: How to pass this string to an exe

Tags: powershell

Powershell can't seem to parse this correctly:

```
mysql.exe '-uroot -p123 DB < c:\test\DB.sql'
```

I also tried this:

```
Start-Process mysql.exe -arg '-uroot -p123 DB < c:\test\DB.sql'
```

Edit: Well this works:

```
 cmd '/c mysql.exe -uroot -p123 DB < dump.sql'
```

This there a more elegant way to do this? Its always a pita to pass args to exe with powershell.

Comment: Does this thread work for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-exe-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that Powershell does not support the `<` character.

A workaround that works for me is :

```
Get-Content dump.sql | ./mysql.exe -uroot -p123 DB
```

However, the `CMD` approach is not so bad.

Comment: I'll take it! I believe gc can also change the -Encoding before passing it through the pipeline which is convenient.

Comment: Right, you can change Encoding : `Get-Content dump.sql -Encoding Unicode | ...`